# Restoring suspended AWS account now Error 500

Tags: django, elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk that was suspended when I forgot to update my payment info when it changed. Once corrected, the env says it's healthy but all I get is 500s. When I go to the direct env URL I get Bad Request 400 errors. The logs mention some errors related to mod_ssl but after some Googling that seems a common warning, maybe not the issue.

Where do you recommend I start troubleshooting this?

*UPDATE*

I thought to check a file from the www/static directory and it is reachable, so I presume that means the server, load balancer, and certificate are all good. I set the ENV for Django to `DEBUG = True`but it's still giving me 500s. Does that mean it's not Django? What's left?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

It was the database (RDS). When AWS suspends your account they take a snapshot of your DB but they don't restore it when the account becomes active again. Restoring the db and adjusting any security groups (not sure if that was necessary) solved it. Hope this helps someone else.